# Process.Kill not killing process

Tags: c#, .net, process

I've written some code to interact with a console app that regularly hangs (due to buggy COM interop I have no control over). My method includes a call to `Process.Kill()` after a timeout, but it doesn't seem to kill the process--it still appears in Task Manager. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
private static string CallBuggyConsoleApp(string path, string ext) {
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = ConsoleAppPath,
        Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", path, ext),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    };
    using (var proc = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
        //The line above should be replaced with:
        //using (var proc = new Process()) {
        //    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        var error = new StringBuilder();
        proc.OutputDataReceived += (_, args) => output.Append(args.Data);
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += (_, args) => error.Append(args.Data);
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        if (proc.WaitForExit((int)ConsoleAppTimeout.TotalMilliseconds)) {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            if (proc.ExitCode != 0) {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Pid {0} exited at {1} with exit code {2} and the following error: {3}",
                    proc.Id, proc.ExitTime, proc.ExitCode, error.ToString()));
            }
            return output.ToString();
        }
        proc.CancelOutputRead();
        proc.CancelErrorRead();
        proc.Kill();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Killed pid {0} at {1}", proc.Id, proc.ExitTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `proc.Start` executed twice ? Does the line `proc.Kill` really execute (check with debugger) ? What sort of COM component is this (COM/COM+/DCOM..) ?

Comment: What OS are you running on, is the process elevated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the inner part of the code where you do the first throw you are not calling the `Kill`.

in general `Exception` should not be used in the throws, it's more usual to throw some derived classes of it like `ApplicationException` or other more specialized ones.

beside this, why are you calling start twice? How would it behave calling start only once? Do you see any difference?

Comment: Argh, that's probably it! I didn't notice I was calling `Start` twice. More than likely the processes hanging around are not the ones being killed.

Comment: No Prob. I would also try your same code but starting another application, like notepad.exe for example, just to make sure it works as expected with another executable...

Comment: Probably a good idea. Thanks. Yep, removing the other call to `Start` seems to have fixed it. I think I was looking for a constructor that accepts a `ProcessStartInfo`, ended up calling `Start`, and forgot about it. I automatically inserted the second call to `Start` after wiring up the event handlers.

Comment: Just a note, Process.Start will return null if the process fails to start.

Comment: @High: Good to know. Thanks. I haven't used `Process` much so I was afraid my code was buggy.